# View over another View use RelativeLayout or?

Tags: android

I have Google map in fragment and i would like to add a View over it in the bottom of the map, The view will change if the user presses Order and that will animate current Bottom View ( it will go down ) and new View will Come from Bottom to "replace it". Now i taught to do this with RelativeLayout to make it over. But is there any other way (better maybe) to do this?

I have read that it might be done with FrameLayout, but i am not sure, on how to do this correctly.[image: Example]

Just to add the new View might be Different Height.

Comment: use relative layout

Comment: see `android.support.design.widget.Snackbar` or `android.support.design.widget.BaseTransientBottomBar` in general

Comment: @pskink will do that, just gonna first try FrameLayout (as i haven't tried them anywhere so it will be good for practice)

Comment: note that `Snackbar` already has the methods like: `show()`, `dismiss()`, `isShown()`, `setDuration()`, `addCallback()` etc...

Comment: Will check Snackbar definitely then, always good to know new things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout`. But I recommend `RelativeLayout` as it is more flexible and easier to use.

Comment: What are the downsides of FrameLayout? Since i haven't used them before would like to know if you have experience with them

Comment: FrameLayout has less customizations but is slightly faster than RelativeLayout. You can search for other differences in Google.